# Command line tool for converting between 3D formats

Tags: osx, media-converter, modeling, command-line

I am looking for a command line tool (i.e. automatable from the command line) for OS X that can convert between various 3D modelling formats, and satisfies the following:

- Supports *any* of the input formats from the list below (taken from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html)).  However, my preferred input format is 3DS.
- It *must* support [Collada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collada) as an output format.

I am already aware of [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) which I can't use due to bugs in its Collada exporter.

---

> 3D Object Geometry Formats
>
> - "PLY" — PLY 3D geometry format (.ply)
> - "OFF", "NOFF" — 3D object file formats (.off, .coff, .noff, .cnoff)
> - "BYU" — BYU 3D geometry format (.byu)
> - "OBJ" — Wavefront OBJ format (.obj)
> - "VTK" — Visualization Toolkit 3D format (.vtk)
>
> 3D Viewing Formats
>
> - "X3D" — X3D XML geometry format (.x3d)
> - "JVX" — JavaView format (.jvx)
> - "VRML" — Virtual Reality Modeling Language format (.vrml)
> - Modeling & Rendering Formats
> - "Maya" — Maya entity files (.ma)
> - "POV" — POV-Ray ray-tracing object description format (.pov)
> - "LWO" — LightWave 3D file format (.lwo)
> - "3DS" — 3D Studio format (.3ds)
> - "RIB" — Renderman interchange format (.rib)
>
> CAD-Related Formats
>
> - "DXF" — AutoCAD 2D & 3D formats (.dxf)
> - "STL" — stereolithography format (.stl)
> - "ZPR" — Z Corp. 3D printer format (.zpr)

Comment: Blender *should* be able to do that I'm pretty sure. But I haven't tried so I can't confirm it. - See [this page for a command line example of blend->obj](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ#Command_Line_Converting). See also the [blender/collada page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import/COLLADA#The_Collada_Exporter).

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56041

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210041/714112

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) import and output formats - I am reasonably sure that most of what you are asking for are available.  If they are you can run blender from the command line and invoke a python script that will, for example, import a file from one format, export it to your required format & quit.

- Numerous [Imports & Exports](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export)
- Export formats include [Collada Export](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import/COLLADA)